# Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in 78user

Tags: php, count

So I am trying to output data ... And it returns "Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in".. Earlier it actually worked, so I don't really get what happend now.. any ideas?

```
public function find($user = null) {
    $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
    $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
    if(!$data->count()) {
        $this->_data = $data->first();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$user = new User();
echo $user->data()->username;
```

Comment: `$data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));` isn't returning an object. Check a user has been returned before attempting to use it.

Comment: how can I work around that, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$data->count()` returns number of rows returned:

```
    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user != null){

        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
        if($data){
        if($data->count() > 0) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
        return false;
 }
```